# Toggle Panels With PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

From some demos and tutorials I've found, I've put together [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/paneltest.php) page which adds toggle panes to a page using values from a mySQL database to populate the fields.

The problem I'm having is that at each layer only the first out of multiple records is shown.

e.g. The screen currently shows 16/03/2012 as the only record, there should be one other record for the 23/02/2012.

Then within the 16/03/2012, the next level should show two items, whereas it is only showing one.

I've been working on this for a while now but I can't seem to find the solution of how to show the correct number of records.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps have a look at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong.

I've added the full script below for reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<title>Panel Test</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".content").hide();
  //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
  jQuery(".heading").click(function()
  {
    jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
  });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css"> 
body {
    margin: 20px auto;
    font: 12px Verdana,Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.layer1 {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 500px;
}

.heading {
margin: 1px;
color: #fff;
padding: 3px 10px;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
background-color:#c30;
}
.content {
padding: 5px 10px;
background-color:#fafafa;
}
p { padding: 5px 0; }
</style> 
</head> 
<?php
mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password")or
die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT userdetails.userid, finds.dateoftrip, detectinglocations.locationname, finds.userid, finds.locationid, detectinglocations.locationid,   finds.findname, finds.finddescription FROM userdetails, finds, detectinglocations WHERE finds.userid=userdetails.userid AND finds.locationid=detectinglocations.locationid AND finds.userid = 1 ORDER BY dateoftrip DESC");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) 
// table is empty 
  echo 'There are currently no finds recorded for this location.'; 
  else
 { 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    { 
    $dateoftrip = $row['dateoftrip']; 
    $findname = $row['findname'];   
{ 
}
}
}
?>
<body>
<div class="layer1"> 
        <p class="heading"><input name="dateoftrip" id="dateoftrip" type="text" value="<?php echo $dateoftrip;?>" disabled="disabled"/></p> 
        <div class="content"> 
            <input name="findname" id="findname" type="text" value="<?php echo $findname;?>" disabled="disabled"/>
        </div> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: In your while loop your just assigning $dateoftrip & $findname over and over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fetching all the records but using only the last one.
You should put this:

```
<div class="layer1"> 
        <p class="heading"><input name="dateoftrip" id="dateoftrip" type="text" value="<?php echo $dateoftrip;?>" disabled="disabled"/></p> 
        <div class="content"> 
            <input name="findname" id="findname" type="text" value="<?php echo $findname;?>" disabled="disabled"/>
        </div> 
</div>
```

in the while loop which fetch the data:

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    { 
     $dateoftrip = $row['dateoftrip']; 
    $findname = $row['findname'];
```

So it will look like this:

```
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        { 
         $dateoftrip = $row['dateoftrip']; 
        $findname = $row['findname'];
echo '<div class="layer1"> 
            <p class="heading"><input name="dateoftrip" id="dateoftrip" type="text" value="'.$dateoftrip.'" disabled="disabled"/></p> 
            <div class="content"> 
                <input name="findname" id="findname" type="text" value="'.$findname.'" disabled="disabled"/>
            </div> 
    </div>';
       }
```

Comment: Hi, this is absolutely brilliant thank you so much. I have however perhaps not explained myself well enough, my sincere apologies. In the case of where there are multiple 'layer2 (content)' records, I'd like to keep them them under the same 'layer 1 (date)' record. So in the case of the 16/03/2012 I'd like the '16/03/2012' layer to appear once with the two 'layer 2 content entries' to appear one after the other. Could you tell me please how I would go about doing this. Once again, apologies for not explaining this properly. Kind regards

Comment: can you show an example for that? (even with just html code?)

Comment: Hi @Ofir, many thanks for your continued help with this. Here is the link to the page. http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/paneltest2.php
I hope that this will help, if not please let me know and I'll be more than happy to provide it in some othewr way. Kind regards

Comment: Oh , this makes it more complex. Try using the "Group by" function in your mysql query. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: Hi, I've given it a try but unfortunately it doesn't work, but you've given me a great start with this. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your output inside your loop.  Also you may have to modify your javascript to account for the multiple content ids.

You should also make the form controls into arrays so you'll be able to parse them if needed (see below).

For example, this is how to modify the form.

```
?>
<body>
<div class="layer1"> 
<?php
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    { 
    $dateoftrip = $row['dateoftrip']; 
    $findname = $row['findname'];   

    $i++;
?>
    <p class="heading"><input name="dateoftrip[]" id="dateoftrip" type="text" value="<?php echo $dateoftrip;?>" disabled="disabled"/></p> 
    <div class="content"> 
        <input name="findname[]" id="findname" type="text" value="<?php echo $findname;?>" disabled="disabled"/>

<?php

{ 
}
}
}    
?>
    </div> 
</div>
```